# non-unique function

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCxpNFIdb-DAn4e259KRfPF8o_rv9O9KY4wOdCG6AM8

**I managed to get the unique output. Another question, is there any way to get the non-unique output with a formula? I tried to search online but most said not possible :/**

So I have a whole column of random numbers+alphabets (Upper and lower cases) like this: *7hyOUGvag1* in column A and I tried to apply **unique(A: A)** for the whole 4000+ rows in column A but it didn't give me the unique output of it, but instead it gave me duplicates of the same output still. Why? I searched everywhere but everyone seems to have no problem with the simple unique function but for me, it didn't work properly...

Is it because my rows of values are randomized with upper and lower cases alphabets + random numbers too?

Comment: Little strange! can you provide more details and if possible code snippet then I can help you better. :)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCxpNFIdb-DAn4e259KRfPF8o_rv9O9KY4wOdCG6AM8/edit?usp=sharing here's the example sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(LOWER(A2:A)))
```

[image: 0]

the `LOWER` can be replaced to `UPPER` or `PROPER`

if you don't want to convert it to either of those modes mentioned above try:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, A2:A, 1, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there another function to get a non-unique output, too? Thanks.

Comment: try: `=FILTER(L2:L, COUNTIF(LOWER(L2:L), LOWER(L2:L))>1)`

Comment: and unique of it: `=UNIQUE(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L, FILTER(L2:L, COUNTIF(LOWER(L2:L), LOWER(L2:L))>1), 1, 0))))`

Answer (score 1):

To get **non-unique values** (duplicate) you can also use:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A), ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF(A2:A,UNIQUE(A2:A))>1 ))
```

Functions used:

- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)